# How to create JSON filter for cloudwatch log events?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

There is three different Sensors log events in my cloudwatch log which will be like OK,Warning and Critical status. Reference for single sensor with all status code be like,

JSON Log events:

```
2020-08-27T19:30:06.998+05:30   {" NumberOfThreads": "Warning"}
2020-08-27T19:43:11.996+05:30   {" NumberOfThreads": "Ok"}
2020-08-27T19:43:11.996+05:30   {" NumberOfThreads": "Critical"}
```

And I want to apply filter like "NumberOfThreads != Ok" means the filter should able to create alarm for either critical state or Warning status.

Text basd log events;

```
2020-08-26T13:05:08.741+05:30   Elasticsearch Ok 
2020-08-26T13:05:08.992+05:30   Elasticsearch Warning
2020-08-26T13:05:08.992+05:30   Elasticsearch Critical
```

I can able to create each filters for "NumberOfThreads: warning" and "NumberOfThreads: Critical" in simple text format. In either method is there any option to define filter which will pick only Elasticsearch critical or warning status only? Help me fix this in text or JSON format please

My Script:

```
SENSOR=$(curl https://mywebpage/admin/monitoring/Elsticsearch/ | awk -F"Sensor<\/th><td>" '{print $2}' |awk -F"<\/td></tr>" '{print $1}')
STATUS=$(curl https://mywebpage/admin/monitoring/Elsticsearch/ | awk -F"Status</th><td>" '{print $2}' |awk -F"</td></tr><tr><th>" '{printf $1}')
echo {\"datetime\": "$TIME", \"$SENSOR\": \"$STATUS\"} >> zoop.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that you can have a logic pick-up text like that with your text-based filter since your logs output structure is not well-defined.

The only solution is, from your application, you need to re-define its logging output again into a well-defined JSON-based log so you can start to filter your logs with JSON, not TEXT.

```
{"datetime": 2020, "thread": "ok"}
```

Here is an example of filtering pattern:

[image: cwlogs-filter-pattern]

Comment: Thanks Leondkr, I will try to include timestamp in JSON format log. Could you please share filter logic for your shared JSON format?

Comment: @rajkumar I have updated with a screenshot as above. You can try with different operators (!=, =) to filter your value :D

Comment: Thank you!! thanks for sharing screenshot. the same method I tried with log previously mentioned log message but it din't work.  Adding date in Json format in message will work? This log message were captured from txt file. Please refer my comment and how can i add date, format as you suggested? I have updated those commands in descreption.

Comment: I have changed my log format as  {"datetime": 2020," NumberOfThreads": "Ok"}  but filter {$.NumberOfThreads = "Ok"} is not working for me.

Comment: @ Leondkr it gt worked for me. instead of {"datetime": 2020, "thread": "ok"} I wish to change date time as {"datetime": 2020.09.16T16.10.40, "NumberOfThreads": "Ok"}. so current filter is not matching with required time stamp.